Cannot convert '<!-' to unsigned int
I'm trying to print the number of atoms in a molecule with rdkit, but i  keep running into this problem even though the code is roughly the same as the tutorial i was following:
[17:11:25] Cannot convert '<!-' to unsigned int on line 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\frede\OneDrive\Skrivebord\Projekter\Python\Kemi\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    text = morphine.GetNumAtoms()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetNumAtoms'

I'm running python in VSCode, using rdkit which i installed directly with pip (I don't have anaconda installed).
Here is the code i wrote:
from rdkit import Chem
import requests

morphine_url = 'https://go.drugbank.com/structures/small_molecule_drugs/DB00295.mol'
morphine_mol = requests.get(morphine_url).text

morphine = Chem.MolFromMolBlock(morphine_mol)

text = morphine.GetNumAtoms()

print(text)

What confuses me the most is the "Cannot convert '<!-' to unsigned int on line 4" part, as i can't find any information as to what '<!-' actually means.
ADDENDUM
actual mol file in drugbank for the molecule above is:
295
  Mrv1909 06162015202D          

 24 28  0  0  1  0            999 V2000
    2.3452    0.0738    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1443   -2.0555    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1443    2.1117    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7533   -0.7968    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100   -0.3844    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245   -0.7968    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0389   -0.3843    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955   -0.7968    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0866    0.2205    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100    0.4405    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0390    0.4404    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.2599    0.2206    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3244    0.8530    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955   -1.6219    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245   -1.6218    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8954    0.8530    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100   -2.0343    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.3444   -1.4318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245    1.6779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955    1.6780    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6099    2.0903    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.7705   -1.3284    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.2769   -1.0363    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.2291   -0.9899    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  8  1  0  0  0  0
  1 16  1  0  0  0  0
 14  2  1  6  0  0  0
  3 20  1  0  0  0  0
  4  7  1  0  0  0  0
  4 12  1  0  0  0  0
  4 18  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  1  0  0  0
  5 10  1  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  6 15  1  0  0  0  0
  6 22  1  1  0  0  0
  7 11  1  0  0  0  0
  7 23  1  6  0  0  0
  8 14  1  0  0  0  0
  8 24  1  1  0  0  0
  9 12  1  0  0  0  0
 10 13  2  0  0  0  0
 10 16  1  0  0  0  0
 11 13  1  0  0  0  0
 13 19  1  0  0  0  0
 14 17  1  0  0  0  0
 15 17  2  0  0  0  0
 16 20  2  0  0  0  0
 19 21  2  0  0  0  0
 20 21  1  0  0  0  0
M  END


<!-- is how you start a comment in HTML. You are going to have to find a way of ignoring text up to the end of the comment, --> See, e.g., https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp

@lastchance there is no comment in the file. probably the request failed

Ah, I didn't care to check out the file. Especially one served up by go.drugbank.com

haha there's a header x-hacker: scraping drugbank? why not download it instead, at go.drugbank.com/downloads

cloudflare is preventing scraping here.

Maybe just print(morphine_mol), before you actually try using any rdkit commands. Then you will see exactly what sort of file you have managed to scrape.

i just noticed the "browser" request uses HTTP/3 maybe that's why requests can't get the data. i don't understand what i just said

I'm not going to try the actual URL to find out.

@lastchance it is not harmeful at all, cannot find API though

@folengateis where did you find this header/or wahtever is called ?? "x-hacker: scraping drugbank? why not download it instead, at go.drugbank.com/downloads" cannot find it anywhere

@pippo1980 browser dev tools. but there are other ways to check the headers sent by the server. with requests r.headers should do

@folengateis yep, but cant find the "x-hacker: scraping drugbank? why not download it instead, at go.drugbank.com/downloads" bit

yep wasnt able to make it working with wget, urllib and others,
so far to me is working only with curl_cffi  :
from rdkit import Chem

from curl_cffi import requests


url = "https://go.drugbank.com/structures/small_molecule_drugs/DB00295.mol"


try:
    # add the target URL and specify the browser to impersonate
    response = requests.get(url, impersonate="chrome110")
    
    print(response.status_code)
    
    data = response.text
    
    print(data)
    
    
    morphine = Chem.MolFromMolBlock(data)

    text = morphine.GetNumAtoms()
    
    print('\n\ntext : ', text)


except Exception as exc:
    
    print(exc)

output:
200
295
  Mrv1909 06162015202D          

 24 28  0  0  1  0            999 V2000
    2.3452    0.0738    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1443   -2.0555    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.1443    2.1117    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.7533   -0.7968    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100   -0.3844    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245   -0.7968    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0389   -0.3843    0.0000 C   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955   -0.7968    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.0866    0.2205    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100    0.4405    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.0390    0.4404    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.2599    0.2206    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3244    0.8530    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955   -1.6219    0.0000 C   0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245   -1.6218    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8954    0.8530    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6100   -2.0343    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    6.3444   -1.4318    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.3245    1.6779    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8955    1.6780    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6099    2.0903    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.7705   -1.3284    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.2769   -1.0363    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.2291   -0.9899    0.0000 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  8  1  0  0  0  0
  1 16  1  0  0  0  0
 14  2  1  6  0  0  0
  3 20  1  0  0  0  0
  4  7  1  0  0  0  0
  4 12  1  0  0  0  0
  4 18  1  0  0  0  0
  5  6  1  0  0  0  0
  5  8  1  0  0  0  0
  5  9  1  1  0  0  0
  5 10  1  0  0  0  0
  6  7  1  0  0  0  0
  6 15  1  0  0  0  0
  6 22  1  1  0  0  0
  7 11  1  0  0  0  0
  7 23  1  6  0  0  0
  8 14  1  0  0  0  0
  8 24  1  1  0  0  0
  9 12  1  0  0  0  0
 10 13  2  0  0  0  0
 10 16  1  0  0  0  0
 11 13  1  0  0  0  0
 13 19  1  0  0  0  0
 14 17  1  0  0  0  0
 15 17  2  0  0  0  0
 16 20  2  0  0  0  0
 19 21  2  0  0  0  0
 20 21  1  0  0  0  0
M  END



text :  21

your text = morphine.GetNumAtoms() should be 21 or I did something wrong

The issue is the bot blocking that they have employed.

The first clue is the "<!-" which is HTML code.
I have then printed out the output of the morphine_mol variable, and it indeed indicates that the issue is due to some kind of blocking they have.

See this text:
    <h2 data-translate="blocked_resolve_headline">What can I do to resolve this?</h2>
        <p data-translate="blocked_resolve_detail">You can email the site owner to let them know you were blocked. Please include what you were doing when this page came up and the Cloudflare Ray ID found at the bottom of this page.</p>

This isn't my field of expertise, but for other tasks similar to this, I have used the API instead.
This seems to be their API information:
https://docs.drugbank.com/v1/
API signup looks like it should be here.
https://dev.drugbank.com/clients/sign_in
Alternatively, if you don't need access in that way - you could save down the file to local, and load it from there.

Thank you so much, haven't thought they could have been blocking my request :)
